# WAN security and port forwarding for IoT

Tags: router, security, wan

I have an esp8266 board that I've set up as a little server. To access it over the web (first forays into making a smart home and IoT) I've used no-ip to deal with dynamic DNS and opened up WAN access with port forwarding (80) on my home router. My question is how secure is this? I've tried only allowing a certain IP address but smart phones use dynamic IPs.

Comment: This question can't be answered without details about the hardware you forwarded port 80... Basically you want to research port 80 vulnerabilities on that piece of hardware.  You're wise to consider this, poor hardware software on that device could in fact lead to more serious issues, on any device.  Is it possible to allow by MAC address?

Comment: The details about the hardware are that it is an [ESP8266](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13678) board running NodeMCU firmware. As I understand it, MAC addresses are very easy to spoof but on top of that, my router does not provide any MAC address filtering unless using a static IP.

Comment: While MAC's are very spoofable, the attacker has to know exactly what MAC to spoof.  It's not perfect, but better than nothing, and better than randomizing the port.  I'm outside the US at the moment and the link to the ESP8266 is blocked for me at this point.

Comment: Try this @Tyson [http://esp8266.co.uk/](http://esp8266.co.uk/)

Comment: Actually thanks for the link, I'm going to order one when I get back home, the product is interesting to me.  I would probably just randomize the port to a high number like @matt Clark suggests, you do that via the port forward.  I.e port 42042 forwards to port 80, another disadvantage to that however is that you access things differently from inside the network, vs outside connections.  Better would be MAC filtering, which although spoofable who's going to know what MAC to spoof.

Comment: Opening a port without limiting what can get through can be a security issue. Consider using a relay service like Yaler.net or PageKite instead of port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with TCP/IP connections, there are 65535 *ports* available to listen on.

Generally, port **80** is used for standard HTTP connections, while port **443** is used for HTTPS.

If you need to open up a common port to the world, be ready to server any request that is made to it.

Another option would to be changing the port you are listening on, this should be a number between 5000 and 65535. By randomizing this port, only you will know how to connect. ( you will need admin access to bind to any port < 1024 )

If you wtill want to server standard HTTP data, the URL would simply be

> http://my.no-iphost.com:55933/my_script

Where 55933 is my secret port.

Comment: Isn't it quite easy to work out what port something is using?

Comment: Generally, bots and bot nets will scrape known ports, SSH:22, TELNET:23, HTTP:80, HTTPS:83, etc... rarely will you become the subject of  a target attack where all 60k ports are scanned. Each service expects the request to be made in a particular manor, so if this is not met either, we wont really know what we are talking to even if we do manage to connect to an open socket.